# Read app.config using XmlDocument

Tags: c#, app-config

I have one app.exe.config file and I am trying to read it via XmlDocument. However, the following code is not working (getting the value as null):

```
XmlDocument appSettingsDoc = new XmlDocument();
appSettingsDoc.Load(@"C:\DBUpgraderConfig\DBUpgrader.exe.config");
XmlNode node = appSettingsDoc.SelectSingleNode("//appSettings");
XmlElement value = (XmlElement)node.SelectSingleNode("UserName");
```

Here is the XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="Server" value="Xeon-s7\MSSQL2008"/>
    <add key="Username" value=""/>
    <add key="Password" value=""/>
  </appSettings>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>
  </startup>
</configuration>
```

Comment: value is coming out to be null

Comment: Is `node` null or `value`?

Comment: value is null, node has good data

Comment: The problem is there's no node named `UserName`, but only a node `add` with an attribute `Key` that's `UserName`. You need to use a different XPath query to get the element with the desired attribute value.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should compare the attribute `key`, instead of trying to get it as node name:

```
XmlElement value = (XmlElement)node.SelectSingleNode("//add[@key='Username']");
```

This will get you the `add` node. You can do whatever you want with it, including getting the attribute `value`.

```
string val = value.Attributes["value"].Value;
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a lot easier using an XPath expression:

```
var appSettingsDoc = XmlDocument.Load(@"C:\DBUpgraderConfig\DBUpgrader.exe.config");

var node = appSettingsDoc.XPathSelectElement("//configuration/appSettings/add[@key = 'Username']");

// for example:
node.Attribute["value"].Value = "John Doe";
```

Answer (score 1):

You are searching for User**N**ame but you have User**n**ame defined.

Comment: This is just part of the problem, but you are right about the typo.